# Why is Include Actual Execution Plan not included in @@Rowcount when it produces a row count?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

While updating a column in a table the last day I was shown a new technique by our Senior DBA to reduce reads and contention.

The pseudo-code is

```
WHILE 
  [always true condition] 
BEGIN 
  UPDATE [...]
IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 BREAK;
END
```

However while running this, I had accidently left Include Actual Execution Plan on so in the Messages tab I was seeing repeating occurrences of this:

```
(1000 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)
```

However the code worked and the WHILE loop worked!

My question is, if including the Actual Execution Plan returns 1 row affected, shouldn't this create an infinite loop?

Why is it not getting counted?

Examples tables below:

```
USE [tempdb];
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UpdateMePlease]
([ID] INT IDENTITY(1, 1), [UselessNote] VARCHAR(10) DEFAULT 'Delete me!', [UpdateValue] VARCHAR(10) NULL)
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[UpdateMePlease] ([UselessNote]) DEFAULT VALUES;
GO 10000

SELECT * FROM [dbo].[UpdateMePlease];

/* turn Actual Execution Plan on here */

WHILE 1 = 1 BEGIN

UPDATE TOP (1000) [dbo].[UpdateMePlease]
SET [UpdateValue] = [UselessNote]
WHERE [UpdateValue] IS NULL;

IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 BREAK

END

-- Clean up
DROP TABLE [dbo].[UpdateMePlease];
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That `DONE_IN_PROC` message from the execution plan is completely independent of your `WHILE` loop, and isn't what's being checked in your conditional `BREAK`. Martin deleted his answer but this is **very much** by design. Your query shouldn't behave differently depending on whether or not your client tool is retrieving execution plans - that would be bad. Execution plans are for monitoring and reviewing, not for influencing actual behavior.

Note that the inverse is also not necessarily a given - not all things that will populate `@@ROWCOUNT` will lead to the `DONE_IN_PROC` message, e.g.

```
DECLARE @foo int, @x varchar(32) = 'hello';
SET @foo = @@ROWCOUNT;
PRINT @foo;
```

This will yield `1` in the messages pane, but you will not see `1 row(s) affected.`

Now, I've always been a big fan of using `SET NOCOUNT ON;`, which renders this question rather moot. But it seems the impact of `DONE_IN_PROC` in modern versions is not what it used to be when I formed this opinion:

- [Performance Surprises and Assumptions : SET NOCOUNT ON](http://sqlperformance.com/2016/02/t-sql-queries/nocount)