# Why does query rowcount change when I enable "include actual execution plan" and "include live query statistics" together?

Tags: sql-server-2016, execution-plan

I have a moderately complex `SELECT` query that utilises inline views and joins. I am intending to see if I can rewrite portions of the query to improve performance. I pasted the query into two SQL sessions in SSMS.

In the first session I ran the query and it took circa 10 seconds and returned 248,069 rows. In the second session I enabled "include actual execution plan" and "include live query statistics" (by pressing those buttons in the toolbar) then ran the query. It took about 3 seconds and returned 248,103 rows. I am running the query in a development environment with only 1 other person accessing this database (and probably not using it at all at the moment).

I then tested various approaches - enabling the same two buttons in the first session = rowcount increases. Disabling those two buttons in second session = rowcount decreases. Repeat. Same result. Query continually runs in about 3 seconds now.

I then tried enabling only 1 of the 2 buttons but in this case the query returned the smaller rowcount - the same as if no button was enabled. Try enabling just the other button - same result - smaller rowcount as if no button was enabled. Re-enable both buttons together, and the rowcount increases again.

I could find only [1 question that's vaguely similar](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/136749/why-is-include-actual-execution-plan-not-included-in-rowcount-when-it-produces) - in the accepted answer there, it states:

> Your query shouldn't behave differently depending on whether or not
> your client tool is retrieving execution plans - that would be bad.
> Execution plans are for monitoring and reviewing, not for influencing
> actual behavior

... and I completely agree!

So why am I getting consistently different row counts when I enable both of those options together?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I found the answer right after posting this question.

If I go to the Results tab, I find there are two result sets in the scenario where both menu options are enabled. The second result set does not appear if you enable only one or the other of the two menu options (or none of them).

The extra result set shows the query plan where each statement in the query is represented as a single row in the result set.

A screen capture of most of the columns is given below. I don't know if this is a documented feature, but these rows look handy to me for evaluating the query plan in a format where you don't have to scroll all around a diagram. Heck, you could even use them as input to a database query to analyse the content. Still not sure why the result set only appears if I enable both those menu items together - nor if you can obtain this result set by some other means.

[image]